# Doctrine insert blank value for primary key

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, primary-key

I know, this topic is already open but I haven't found the right answer. The problem is:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag_name", type="string", length=200)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $tagName;
```

This is a section of the entity "tag" that have a pk called tag_name. Well, this php code should insert a tag into db:

```
$tag1 = new Tag();
        $tag1->setBusinessEmail("root@localhost.com");
        $form= $this->createForm(TagType::class, $tag1);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $tag1->setTagName("ttt");
        if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($tag1);
        $em->flush();

        .......
```

But tag_name value into db is blank. I've already tried to change value and/or delete "* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")" but nothing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Did you try changing the strategy to "SEQUENCE" instead of none?  

    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@ORM\GeneratedValue()`? Since you manually set the tag, there is no value to be generated anyway and you always want to manually specify it, if I understand your code snippet correctly.

Comment: First of all: thanks. Then; yes I tried to change strategy to "SEQUENCE" and also to remove @ORM\GeneratedValue() but again; nothing. I haven't any error and also field are consistent with database constraints.

Comment: Tag table is associated with another table. Can relation cause this trouble?

Comment: I solved. Oh yes.